# Posting variables from PHP to another PHP without page redirect

Tags: php, post, redirect

I have 2 PHP scripts, one residing on Server A and another on server B. I need to pass variables received via POST by PHP A to PHP B without the page redirecting. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curl,

```
$curlHandler = curl_init();

    $curlOpts = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.example.com/Target.php",
            CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($_POST, "", "&"),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "MyScript/0.1"
             );
     curl_setopt_array($curlHandler, $curlOpts);

     if (false===($responseString=curl_exec($curlHandler))) {

           exit("0 - No connection to server.");
     }

    echo $responseString;
```

If you send POST-Data to this scrip it will send it to http://www.example.com/Target.php.

If it gets `$_POST["Foo"] = 10` then it will send `$_POST["foo"] = 10` to Target.php.
It uses all Post variables it gets with the same names and values.

EDIT:

If you want to send some vars you can do it like this:

```
$vars = array("key" => "value", 
              "key2" => "value2",
              ...
             );
```

after doing so you have to change the line from the example above:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($_POST, "", "&"),
```

needs to be changed to

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($vars, "", "&"),
```

Comment: How do I retrieve the variable in Target.php? I can do a $_REQUEST['target'] but for the variable name 'target' what do I replace it with?

Comment: I see. So if I am not wrong, I declare all the POST variables before `$curlHandler = curl_init();`?

Comment: yeah, but see my last edit, it is not neccessary to fill it into $_POST ;-)

Answer (score 0):

By performing a POST request from within your PHP script. There are lot's of tutorials out there on how to do this (e.g. [this one](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/three-ways-to-make-a-post-request-from-php)). You just transmit the POST parameter values to the second server this way and there is no need for a page redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [php curl function](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to post your variables to another server

Answer (score 0):

Do you know jquery. It has a simple way of doing exactly what you want. It is very easy to learn. Check on this example http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: yup. but here I am trying to pass variables from my PHP to another. I am not using javascript